# Is it possible to access View object created in Java, through Native code?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

Is it possible to access View object created in Java, through Native code? I want create some layout with controls (Buttons, Text view, etc.) using Java. And after  draw in some region of this layout through native code (using OpenGL ES). It is possible?

Comment: You know that on Android, you can work with OpenGL from Java, too, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

In general yes.

This pattern is called facade. Class which integrate more classes in self and expose simple methods, which can be called from native code.
You pass this object to native code and access it from native code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Comment: It is very general statement. May be somebody know way how possible integrate layout with controls and OpenGL ES rendering?